# TypeAhead don't reload the first time when I delete a character

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4, typeahead.js

When I start to write in my TypeAhead the option list works but if I delete a character always appear the result of the previous looking for.

```
<input id="OficinaContablePT"
   type="text"
   class="form-control"
   [(ngModel)] = "model"
   [ngbTypeahead]="searchOC"
   [inputFormatter]="formatter"
   [resultFormatter]="formatter"/>
```

---

```
searchOC = (text$: Observable<string>) =>
  text$.pipe(
    debounceTime(100),
    distinctUntilChanged(),
    map(term => term.length < 3 ? this.listaContables = []
        : (this.oficinaContable(1, term).filter(v => 
   v.codigo.toLocaleLowerCase().indexOf(term.toLocaleLowerCase()) > -1).slice(0, 10)))
  )
```

If I look for "L0103" appear "L0103AZSDF, L0103QWER" but if I delete a character ("L010") must appear "L0101, L0102, L0103ASDF, L010QWER" and only appear "L0103AZSDF, L0103QWER"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I solved it,

To solve it I needed to create a '(ngModelChange)' that charge a static array with my method of search and then use this array in the search component and dont use the method in the search.